# MongoDB query is too slow with $unwind, How can I optimise my query?

Tags: database, mongodb, algorithm, data-structures, mongodb-query

I am tyring to get some **results from MongoDB collection**, as I have more than 50 millions of records sometimes, I need to fetch data around 2-3 millions, as it take a lot of time to get data, I am wondering if I can **improve query or the data structure**.

**data** -

```
    [
{
     
    "_id": "6427f8af2cbc676fb2ffa0f8",
    "articleid": "166494143",
    "clientid": "M0036",
    "clientname": "Microsoft",
    "keyword": [
        {
            "keyword": "",
            "keyid": "2524",
            "keytpe": "My Competitor Keyword",
            "companyissue": "Apple"
        },
        {
            "keyword": null,
            "keyid": "2529",
            "keytpe": "My Competitor Keyword",
            "companyissue": "Google"
        }
    ],
    "rejected": 0
},
{
   
    "_id": "64281e6a2cbc676fb2131702",
    "articleid": "166500589",
    "clientid": "M0036",
    "clientname": "Microsoft",
    "keyword": [
        {
            "keyword": "",
            "keyid": "2526",
            "keytpe": "My Competitor Keyword",
            "companyissue": "Cisco "
        }
    ],
    "rejected": 0
},
{
   
    "_id": "642735062cbc676fb2a87e67",
    "articleid": "166474027",
    "clientid": "M0036",
    "clientname": "Microsoft",
    "keyword": [
        {
            "keyword": "",
            "keyid": "2529",
            "keytpe": "My Competitor Keyword",
            "companyissue": "Google"
        }
    ],
    "rejected": 0
   
}

]
```

**Requirement** - **I need to get the count of** `keyword.companyissue`.
result needs be like this - `[{"_id":"Google","count":1507},{"_id":"Microsoft","count":979}]`

I have **index** the required field - `KEYWORD.COMPANYISSUE`

**Query** -
(As I am aware unwind will be slow for large dataset, but can we do this in a more efficient way without unwind)

```
    var a = [ 
        { $unwind: "$keyword" },
        { "$match": { "keyword.companyissue": { "$ne": "null" } } },
        {
            $group:
            {
                _id: { articleid: "$articleid", companys: "$keyword.companyissue" }
            }
        }, { $sort: { count: -1 } },
        {
            $group: {
                _id: "$_id.companys",
                count: { $sum: 1 }
            }
        }, { $sort: { count: -1 } }
    ];
```

Comment: match before unwind?

Comment: what you mean by before unwind

Comment: bring match stage before unwinding so lesser do to unwind. don't know if it'll improve much tho

Comment: oh! I did but not very efficient as there are very less `null` values

Comment: also ca reduce stages i gues https://mongoplayground.net/p/TMJ69bXgau6

Comment: Ya, swap the position for `$unwind` and `$match` stage. As only when `$match` stage is at the first stage, the query will able to be hit the index. You may use [`.explain()`](https://database.guide/find-out-if-a-query-uses-an-index-in-mongodb/) to check whether your query hits the index.

Comment: @YongShun thank you I am trying this explain() method, also for a data of 5-6 months it is taking around 1.5 minutes, I feel if I can reduce it to under 30 seconds.

Comment: @cmgchess The `$match` at first stage does not work. Do you like to suppress the entire document if just one `companyissue` is null? I guess you must use `$filter`

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit ah right it ignores the whole array if there is a null

Comment: can I leverage redis to cache the keyword.companyissue and retrieve data from there, is it a good solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   {
      $project: {
         _id: 0,
         keyword: {
            $filter: {
               input: "$keyword",
               cond: { $ne: ["$$this.companyissue", null] }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   {
      $set: {
         keyword: {
            $map: {
               input: { $setUnion: "$keyword.companyissue" },
               as: "company",
               in: {
                  company: "$$company",
                  count: {
                     $size: {
                        $filter: {
                           input: "$keyword",
                           cond: { $eq: ["$$this.companyissue", "$$company"] }
                        }
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   { $unwind: "$keyword" },
   {
      $group: {
         _id: "$keyword.company",
         count: { $sum: "$keyword.count" }
      }
   },
   { $sort: { count: -1 } }
])
```

It makes a pre-count on document level and removes all not needed data. Thus the amount of unwinded data should be much lower. Make only one `$sort`